# Parse curl response from github api

Tags: php, api, curl, github

I'm a newbie in php but I'm trying to learn right now. What i want to make : 
Send a curl request to github api like this :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/language:' . $lang);
```

And when i receive the result to display like a nice html page. The response that I'm receiving right now is displayed like the one written in github api documentation http://developer.github.com/v3/search/.

This is the first time I'm trying to learn PHP, but not the first time I've been web developing ( I've been contributing to a Hakyll based blog these weeks ).

My question is : How could i parse the results to format them nicely in a html page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are returned via **`JSON`**. You can make use of [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for that.

Pass your **`cURL`** `$response` to this function. Such that `print_r(json_decode($response,1));`

### Example of how to do it

```
<?php
$json='{
  "text_matches": [
    {
      "object_url": "https://api.github.com/repositories/3081286",
      "object_type": "Repository",
      "property": "name",
      "fragment": "Tetris",
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": "Tetris",
          "indices": [
            0,
            6
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "object_url": "https://api.github.com/repositories/3081286",
      "object_type": "Repository",
      "property": "description",
      "fragment": "A C implementation of Tetris using Pennsim through LC4",
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": "Tetris",
          "indices": [
            22,
            28
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';


$jarr=json_decode($json,1);
echo $jarr['text_matches'][0]['object_url']; //"prints" https://api.github.com/repositories/3081286
```

Comment: Thanks. Nothing happens when i use that, but I'll look into it.

Comment: You can try out the example i posted (it will work as it is tested) , Also, try your attempts and update it in the question so we could know where you are stuck.